# How do conditional insertions work in VS Code grammars?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate

TextMate 1.5.1 documents [Conditional Insertions](https://macromates.com/manual/en/regular_expressions#conditional_insertions) here and VS Code seems to implement a lot of the same features. But, I cannot figure out how to get them working. It is my understanding that the following pattern should work. Can anyone shed any light into this? Does TextMate 2 include this feature or is there another way to achieve this?

```json
"string": {
        "name": "string.quoted.(?2:single:double).sass",
        "begin": "((')|\")",
        "end": "(\\1)",
        "beginCaptures": {
            "0": {
                "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.sass"
            }
        },
        "endCaptures": {
            "0": {
                "name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.sass"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am expecting these results:

```
'test' // 'test' => 'string.quoted.single.sass'; ' => punctuation.definition.string.begin.sass, punctuation.definition.string.end.sass
"test" // 'test' => 'string.quoted.double.sass'; " => punctuation.definition.string.begin.sass, punctuation.definition.string.end.sass
```